# how to get only the top 100 matching results in neo4j FT index queries

Tags: rest, lucene, indexing, neo4j, neo4jphp

how to get only the top 100 matching results in neo4j FT index queries. I am sure for common searches the index will match thousands of nodes but i would need only say the top 100 highest scored matches. What configuration settings or query context should i set to achieve this. How is this possible in REST API without cypher. Is cypher a must to get these 100 top scored full text matches. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be using Cypher's `LIMIT` clause. Since you explicitly asked for non cypher solutions, the only option is to write a [unmanaged extension](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) that [runs the index query](http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.3/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/ReadableIndex.html#query%28java.lang.Object%29) and does not fully consume the iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion this seems a plausible option. From this i understand that i can create a REST service alternative which  will return top scored 100 matches. But would it make a huge difference in performance if (1)we consume the top 100 matches of the iterator and pass it as a response to REST call OR (2)alternatively if we return all the thousand matches as a response to the REST call and then consume the top 100 matches. I say this because i am calling the REST from the same physical server so ultimately the same amount of memory seems to be consumed in both the cases.

Comment: Since the iterator is lazy that make a significant difference when you don't consume unneeded results. Additionally is the HTTP overhead and for marshalling json.